# 2-Dimensional array storage

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, storage

I have recently stumbled upon this problem. I want to store a 2-dimensional int array in a file to be read later. Is there any way of doing this other than simple txt.file? (Java as programming language)

Comment: All arrays are serializable (provided their elements are, which is definitely the case for `int`). Just write it with an `ObjectOutputStream`; read it back with an `ObjectInputStream`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated by @Andy you can use `ObjectOutputStream` to serialize array to a file

```
int[][] intArray = new int[5][5];
//Code to populate array

// serialize array
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("array.dat");
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
oos.writeObject(intArray);
```

And then it can be read back as an array from file using `ObjectInputStream`

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("array.dat");
ObjectInputStream iis = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
intArray = (int[][]) iis.readObject();
```

Hope this helps.